# How to remove emacsclient and emacsclient.emacs from linux(debian)

Tags: terminal-emacs, linux, debian

I have installed emacs using apt.
I have already tried:

> apt purge emacs

> apt purge emacs-gtk

When I tried to remove emacsclient using apt. It says

> "E: Unable to locate package emacsclient"

Comment: emacsclient or emcasclient? ;-) Not sure this question is on topic, but anyway, on my machine /usr/bin/emacsclient.emacs is in package emacs-bin-common.

Comment: It is emacsclient. It was typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=emacsclient), `emacsclient.emacs` is in the package `emacs-bin-common`.